# HttpResponse writer doesn't print "\n"

Tags: java, angular, servlets

I'm coding a Java Servlet that has to handle my request and return a string as response.

The response is composed by 2 lines, so I write my servlet code:

```
response.getWriter().println(line1 + "\n");
response.getWriter().println(line2);
```

But in my html page, the response is displayed as an unique line. How can I display my response in 2 different line ?

My project is an Angular2 project and I retrieve the response in this way:

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

this.http.get(url)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => response.text())
```

**EDIT**

I solved changing my HTML  result, by adding the attribute innerHTML:

```
<div innerHTML="{{response text}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Linebreaks and other whitespace are all treated in HTML as a single space. This has nothing to do with Java, Angular, or servlets.

If you want to break a line in HTML, you use separate elements, or a `<br>`, or a `pre` formatted element, or various other options.

```css
.pre {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
Line 1
Line 2
Note there is no displayed line break
</div>
<hr>
<div>
Line 1
<br>Line 2
<br>Note there is a displayed line break
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div>Line 1</div>
  <div>Line 2</div>
  <div>Note there is a displayed line break</div>
</div>
<hr>
<pre>
Line 1
Line 2
Note there is a displayed line break
</pre>
<hr>
<div class="pre">
Line 1
Line 2
Note there is a displayed line break
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know what you tell me but if I write <br>, my response will display "<br>".

Comment: @dona: That means something, somewhere is escaping HTML special characters but not also converting linebreaks into `<br>` or similar. You'll need to find that and make it stop doing that. It's something between the code you currently have outputting `\n` and what the browser actually receives.

Comment: I tried: response.getWriter().write("<html><body>");
 response.getWriter().write(line1 + " <br/>");
 response.getWriter().write(line2);
 response.getWriter().write("</body></html>"); I set my response.contentType to text/html too but it doesn't work. I don't understand how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Because `\n` is whitespace in HTML, and HTML ['user agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing output inter-word space'](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#whitespace). Perhaps you are looking for `<br/>`?

NB You should be using `print()`, or `write()`, not `println()`.

Comment: Thank you EJP, I know what you tell me but if I write <br/>, my response will display "<br/>".

Comment: That's not what I wrote. Try again.

Comment: <br> is fine, try again EJP.

Comment: I've tried: response.getWriter().write(line1 + "<br/>");
response.getWriter().write(line2); but nothing changes. I set my response.contentType to text/html too.

Comment: @TedTrippin Nevertheless it is not what I wrote. I'm not answerable to the OP for things I didn't tell him to do.